# Ascii Table in Java

Tags: java, ascii

I'm having trouble creating a table that is used for a game. It needs to have

- 3 Human characters `@`,
- 2 Monsters `#`,
- 3 Treasure Chests `*`
- and 4 Obstacles `O`.

The table needs to be 10 by 10 squares and gaps should be filled with `.`
It should kinda look something like this:

```
   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 1 . @ . * . . . . . .
 2 . . . . . # . . O .
 3 . . . . . . . . . .
 4 . . . . . . . . . .
 5 . . . # . . @ . . .
 6 . . O . . . . . . .
 7 . . . . O . . . O .
 8 . . . . . . * . . .
 9 . * . . . . . . . .
10 . . . . . . . @ . .
```

I also need to be able to move the chapters in the end. This is my currant code. But I can only get it so that the `.` and `@` appear, otherwise I just get errors. Even when using `else if`:

```
package test;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class Test {

    public static void show(boolean[][] grid) {

        String s = "";

        for (boolean[] row : grid) {

            for (boolean col : row)

                if (col)

                    s += "@ ";

                else

                    s += ". ";

            s += "\n";

        }

        System.out.println(s);

    }

    public static boolean[][] gen() {

        boolean[][] grid = new boolean[10][10];

        for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++)

            for (int c = 0; c < 10; c++)

                if (Math.random() > 0.2)

                    grid[r][c] = true;

        return grid;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean[][] world = gen();

        show(world);

        System.out.println();

        world = nextGen(world);

        show(world);

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (s.nextLine().length() == 0) {

            System.out.println();

            world = nextGen(world);

            show(world);

        }

    }

    public static boolean[][] nextGen(boolean[][] world) {

        boolean[][] newWorld

        = new boolean[world.length][world[0].length];

        int num;

        for (int r = 0; r < world.length; r++) {

            for (int c = 0; c < world[0].length; c++) {

                num = numNeighbors(world, r, c);

                if (occupiedNext(num, world[r][c]))

                    newWorld[r][c] = true;

            }

        }

        return newWorld;

    }

    public static boolean occupiedNext(int numNeighbors, boolean occupied) {

        if (occupied && (numNeighbors == 2 || numNeighbors == 3))

            return true;

        else if (!occupied && numNeighbors == 3)

            return true;

        else

            return false;

    }

    private static int numNeighbors(boolean[][] world, int row, int col) {

        int num = world[row][col] ? -1 : 0;

        for (int r = row - 1; r <= row + 1; r++)

            for (int c = col - 1; c <= col + 1; c++)

                if (inbounds(world, r, c) && world[r][c])

                    num++;

        return num;

    }

    private static boolean inbounds(boolean[][] world, int r, int c) {

        return r >= 0 && r < world.length && c >= 0 &&

        c < world[0].length;

    }

}
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what will help me get all the symbols in?

Answer (score 2):

You're using a boolean 2-D array for your grid.  So each entry can only have two values.  If you switch it to be int[][] for example, then you could specify different values for the different types of objects that could inhabit that cell.  Say for example:

1. Human "@"
2. Monster "#"
3. Treasure Chest "*"
4. Obstacle "O"

And maybe use 0 = Unoccupied ".", since integers default to zero anyways.

Answer (score 2):

The data structure you use to store your data (`boolean[][]`) accommodates only two distinct values per cell, but you need five.  You can keep a similar program structure but accommodate the number of distinct values you need by changing to a `byte[][]`.

Furthermore, you could simplify at least the `show()` method by employing an array to map those `byte` values to the appropriate display character.

Perhaps this will get you going in a useful direction:

```
    private final static char[] DISPLAY_SYMBOLS = { '.', '@', '#', '*', 'O' };
    // ...

    public static void show(byte[][] grid) {
        for (byte[] row : grid) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            for (byte col : row) {
                sb.append(DISPLAY_SYMBOLS[col]).append(' ');
            }

            System.out.println(sb.toString());
        }
    }
```